# Arraylist not getting repopulated after using notifyDataSetChanged() in java andriod

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter

I am trying to use arraylist.clear and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to clear an arraylist the list is cleared successfully but when i try to reload the list again with some data the list is not showing despite the arraylist.size showing the total number of items which is greater than 0. Here is the method to create the initial list

```
private void getTH(int ID) {
        url = "url";
        mainAdapterClasses = new ArrayList<>();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject0 = new JSONObject(response);
                String code = jsonObject0.getString("code");;
                if (code.matches("200")) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("items");
                    if(jsonArray.length() == 0){
                        txtEmpty.setText(String.format("%s %s", getString(R.string.no), getString(R.string.empty)));
                    } else {
                        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(k);
                            String na = jsonObject.optString("na", "NA");
                            String aT = jsonObject.optString("Type", "NA")
                            
                            MainAdapterClass mainAdapterClass = new MainAdapterClass();
                            mainAdapterClass.setName(na);
                            mainAdapterClass.setType(aT);
                            mainAdapterClasses.add(mainAdapterClass);

                        }
                            mainAdapter = new TAdapter(WalletHome.this, mainAdapterClasses);
                            listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
                            mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            txtEmpty.setText("Data Is Here"+mainAdapterClasses.size());
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+getString(R.string.unknown_err), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

and here is the code that is supposes to reload the list

```
    @Override
    public void getRadioButtonListener1(int position) {
        WClass wClass = stateClassArrayList.get(position);
        wId = wClass.getWId();
        if(mainAdapter.getCount() > 0){
            mainAdapterClasses.clear();
            mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getTH(id);
        }
    }
```

I tried to log the issue here the method is getting the current total of items everytime i run the method the only issue is that the list is not getting populated with the new data once it is initially cleared.

```
txtEmpty.setText("Data Is Here"+mainAdapterClasses.size());
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like you are creating and populating the "MainAdapterClass" with the "na" and "aT" variables but not using them anywhere, so you are not really adding items to mainAdapterClasses array.

Second of all, in the for loop you are recreating and setting the adapter each time. I would advise creating and setting the adapter outside of the foor loop once you have your array (mainAdapterClasses) populated with the requested items.

```
for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(k);
    String na = jsonObject.optString("na", "NA");
    String aT = jsonObject.optString("Type", "NA")
    
    MainAdapterClass mainAdapterClass = new MainAdapterClass();
    mainAdapterClass.setName(na);
    mainAdapterClass.setType(aT);

    mainAdapterClasses.add(mainAdapterClass);
} //for 
mainAdapter = new TAdapter(WalletHome.this, mainAdapterClasses);
listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
txtEmpty.setText("Data Is Here"+mainAdapterClasses.size());
```

Comment: Thanks I have modified the code but the list is still empty and the mainAdapterClasses.size() is still showing the number of items correctly

Comment: Remember that once you plug the mainAdapterClasses to the TAdapter you should be controlling your item list from the adapter to ensure consistency. Meaning that you shouldn't call a size from the mainAdapterClasses array but rather from the TAdapter class. So in the radioButtonListener you should check whether the mainAdapter.getItemCount > 0

Comment: @ x-devel i have updated the adapter line to                                `if(mainAdapter.getCount() > 0){
            mainAdapterClasses.clear();
        }` but the issue still persists

Comment: @SerenityEmmanuel What if in the listener you write something like: 
`if(mainAdapter.getCount() > 0){ mainAdapter.clear(); //implement this method that clears the array inside the adapter}
mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
getTH(id);`

then in the getTH method uncomment the mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in the for loop

Comment: tried that still not working you can check the question again for the new code update

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `mainAdapterClass` to the ArrayList.

```
for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(k);
    String na = jsonObject.optString("na", "NA");
    String aT = jsonObject.optString("Type", "NA")
    
    MainAdapterClass mainAdapterClass = new MainAdapterClass();
    mainAdapterClass.setName(na);
    mainAdapterClass.setType(aT);

    mainAdapterClasses.add(mainAdapterClass); // Add this line.
}
```

Don't setAdapter inside the loop. Just add items and then set the adapter outside the loop.
Also calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting adapter doesn't make sence.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   // ...
}

listview.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
```